# How would you solve the equation $-4450(1.05)^{n}+240n+4800=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

I've formed a difference equation to calculate the rate of change in a population of weasels, which I then solved to find tan expression for the population at time $n$. The expression I got was $y(n)=-4450(1.05)^{n}+240n+4800$. How would you find the value of $n$ for which $y(n)=0$?

Comment: Newton-raphne method :P

Comment: Your best bet is numerically. Someone will probably point out that there is an 'exact' solution in terms of the Lambert $W$ function. But as we have to evaluate the Lambert $W$ function numerically, writing the solution in that form has no especial advantage.

Comment: @SimonS. You are totally right but there are very good approximations of $W(x)$ for small $x$ and large $x$ and they do not need many terms.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, after I wrote that I felt I could write a paragraph of caveats: "Unless you already have access to a look up table for $W$; or you are sufficiently well versed in the numerical methods library of your favorite programming language that there is a library function for $W$; or ..."

Comment: @SimonS. These are given in Wijipedia (and I use them a lot). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I didn't know it was so easily available. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @SimonS. Search on MSE for Lambert. You will see an incredible number of problems numerically solved using these expansions. Lambert is one of most loved functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-linear equation which cannot be solved algebraically (unless you "know" about LabertW functions).

Usually this sort of equation is solved numerically (i.e. find an approximate solution) by software (either a graphing calculator or some sort of mathematical software like Maple, Mathematica, etc).

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%924450%281.05%5En%29%2B240n%2B4800%3D0) provides a free online route to a solution.

Alpha says that $n \approx 9.55784$ is a solution.

Maple:
[image]